# In my Vue project I want to set user status, is logged in or not with cookies

Tags: vue.js

When a user is logged in I want to set the user status logged in. I use Vue-cookies. I want to watch if the cookie is set user status changes to 1. and I need to access this status in all the components.
I don't use Vuex.

I tried to use local storage. But it is not deleted.

```
Vue.prototype.$localStorage = new Vue({
  data: { 
     // token property returning the ls token value 
     token: window.localStorage.getItem('token') 
  },
  watch:{ 
     // watcher listening for changes on the token property
     // to ensure the new value is written back to ls 
     token(value){ window.localStorage.setItem('token', value) } 
  }
})
```

is there any code like this one for watching cookies.

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Comment: What is a question, what do you need?

Comment: Cookies are not reactive. Are you going to check every time you do something if user is logged in?

Comment: yes, i want when my cookie has token i change user status to true and if doesnt have cookie set the user status false

Comment: i dont know how can i watch my cookie globaly

Comment: I am looking for a code like above to watch my cookies

Comment: You can not watch cookie as they are not reactive.

Comment: so what is your idea to solve this problem?(showing the user status in all pages)

Comment: LocalStorage is something completely different from cookies. IF you want to know whether a cookie with a given name and/or value is currently set on the browser - you should simply call `$cookies.isKey(keyName) ` or `$cookies.get(keyName)`